# Semi Transparent overlay over HTML video is always behind video

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code in an element:

```html
<div id="video-container">
    <video id="video" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img src="backup-img.png">
    </video>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a colour filter overlay via rgba using the following CSS:

```css
#video-container{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100vw; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color:rgba(10,10,10,0.8);
  z-index: 100;
}

#video{
  position: relative;
  z-index:-100;
}
```

The trouble is, no matter what I do to #video-container and #video, the layer with the rgba style is always behind the video when I test it. I have tried using z-indexes, adding empty content, but nothing seems to get the layer to go over top of the video.

Ideally the filter layer should be the same size as the video regardless of screen dimensions, but I can't get to that point yet since the filter layer refuses to go on top.

This seems to be the case in all the browsers I have (firefox, chrome, edge)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share your code on Codepen, or jsfiddle. Try adding an image of what you try to achieve but what exactly is the output :) I would like to help you with this bro

Comment: paste this into a basic html file and it produces the same result. 
```
<style>
    #video-container{
  content:"";
  min-width: 100vw; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgba(255,10,10,0.8);
  z-index: 100;
}

#video{
  position: relative;

  z-index:-100;
}
</style>

<div id="video-container">
 <img id="video" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300">
</div>
```
As you can see, the kitten is not nearly as red as the rest of the screen.

Comment: also on codepen: https://codepen.io/nmorrish1/pen/WNGoVJY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add after or before to #video-container, like this:

```css
#video-container::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100vw; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color:rgba(10,10,10,0.8);
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

if you want to transparent layer be the same size of your video, add relative position to your container:

```css
#video-container { position: relative;}
```

and change the width and height of your pseudo-class to 100%;

```css
#video-container::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color:rgba(10,10,10,0.8);
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Anyway, it takes the size of a parent that have first relative position.

Comment: because the parent contains its children.

Comment: When we use positon:absolute; Technically our element comes out of the normal flow. Then we use z-indexes to control what comes on top or behind. And life becomes easy :)

Comment: One issue, though. How do I ensure #video-container::after retains the same size as #video? Setting the width and height to any combination of %, px, or vw/vh breaks down the moment the screen is resized.

Comment: @N.MORR : I feel with my solution you no longer need to use pseudo-class.  Try it once and let me know, if it is working fine with updated sizes. :)

Comment: if you want to transparent layer be the same size of your video, add relative position to your container:  #video-container {
  position: relative;} and change the width and height of your pseudo-class to 100%;

Comment: Aha, yes, this does the trick. I just use negative margins to bring the filter over top.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Have just figured out the wierd behavior. The reason why this is happening is because *`The child element is in a lower stacking context due to its parent’s z-index level`*.

**There are two solutions to this problem:**

**1.**  Move the `#video` img element outside of the `**#video-container**` parent, and into the main stacking context of the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="video-container"></div>
<img id="video" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#video-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(10, 255, 51, 0.8);
  z-index: 100;
}

#video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

**2.** Remove positioning from the `#video-container`, so it won’t limit the `#video's` z-index.

```css
#video-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(10, 255, 51, 0.8);
}

#video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
      <img id="video" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" />
</div>
```

Get More information from the link : https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails if there are any other background styles in the project. There is a #ffffff background across the actual project I am working on, and the video disappears behind that that if the video has a negative z-index. Is there any reason why an element with a higher z-index shouldn't go over top?

Comment: I myself am a bit confused about this behaviour,. Try setting z-index: -5; on that background div, a more negative value than our #video's , see if our video is shown.

Comment: Have figured our the main reasons why this was happening and updated my answer as well. Read from here. https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/. This initially looked confusing to me also. But now it is clear why this wierd behaviour was happening. Answer that I have updated inow is indeed the main reason and should be the accepted one for other's to benefit from. Do rate and accept the answer only if this makes sense now. By the way I thank you for letting me google around and reaching to the conclusion :) Thank you

Comment: I think your question is a nice one and I have rated it for you. Happy Coding :)